# How to handle dynamically changing id in dropdown and if I select class then it shows three matching nodes

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, selenium2, selenium-webdriver

html snippet:

```
<div id="isc_PT" class="selectItemText" tabindex="5637" style="width:123px;height:12px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;" $9a="$9d" $89="isc_SelectItem_8" aria-expanded="false"></div>
```

If I select class I have 3 matching nodes. How can I handle that?

I have tried with

```
//div[contains(@id,'isc_PT')]

WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'isc_FX')]"));
            Select se=new Select(element);
            se.selectByVisibleText("MDialog");
```

Comment: This looks like Java, am I correct in my assumption? If so, which version are you using? Are you using Groovy as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
     WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='selectItemText'])[2]"));
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                element.click();
                Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//nobr[text( )='MDialog'])[4]")).click();  
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nobr[text()='MDialog']")).click();
                element.click();
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                driver.findElement(By.name("description")).sendKeys("MDialog");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Comment: Is it works now?

Comment: always try to avoid use of 'Thread.sleep' in your code.
Instead of this you may use 'implicitlyWait'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Select` is not working with Div or any other element.

> **`Select` are use only with element is having `Select` tag and inside it, only having  `option` tags.**

**Solution :**

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'isc_FX')]"));
element.click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='MDialog']")).click();
```

Try this.

Comment my answer If any query.

Comment: no not working ,not able to find the x path it is changing

Comment: no not working.<div id="isc_1BW" class="selectItemText" tabindex="8913" style="width:123px;height:12px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;" $9a="$9d" $89="isc_SelectItem_12" aria-expanded="false"></div>

Comment: you can use class property. Please let me know If it is working or not so I can update answer.  driver.findElement(By.className("selectItemText"));

Comment: element is not click able at point element.click();